# Changing the size of a HICON

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, dpi

I am using a button which is not DPI aware. I am using it everywhere in my code so ideally I'd like to add a few lines in the SetIcon of that button.

The SetIcon method (unsurprisingly) takes a HICON as a parameter - and I want to change the icon depending on the DPI resolution (so most of the time increase its size).

*edit*
As pointed below, my question was not clear. I do not want to change the size of the icon - as read from a resource - but I want to transform a HICON od 16x16 into a new HICON of 40x40. I have got some code which reads a PNG (which returns a HICON) and LoadImage (nor LoadIconWithScaleDown) won't work with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Changing the question after answer has already been given is not recommended. Also your modified question is still unclear. You have "some code" which makes 16x16 icon, just get it to make 40x40 icon. Or scale up the icon if you don't care about resolution. What does that have to do with DPI? unless your DPI settings is at 250 percent!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've asked OP to edit his question for clarification. I think it's quite clear right now. I currently don't have time to update my answer, which would propably go like: 1. Create a 32 bpp memory device context. 2. `DrawIconEx()` into that memory DC to scale the icon. 3. `CreateIcon()` from the bits of the memory DC to turn that back into an icon.

Comment: @zett42 - thanks for this - would the transparency work though?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx) (available since Windows Vista) to load an icon image in the desired size, which is already scaled by the DPI scale factor.

Another answer suggests using `LoadImage()`, but `LoadIconWithScaleDown()` will greatly improve image quality in cases where an exact match of the desired image size is not available in the icon resource. In this case, `LoadImage()` loads the image with the next *lower* size and scales that up, whereas `LoadIconWithScaleDown()` loads the next *bigger* image and scales that down, which makes the scaled image appear more detailed and sharper.

```
int cx = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSMICON );  // scaled for system DPI!
int cy = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSMICON );  // scaled for system DPI!

HICON hIcon = NULL;
HRESULT hr = LoadIconWithScaleDown( AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1),
                                    cx, cy, &hIcon );

if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    button.SetIcon( hIcon );
}
```

**Note:** I'm using [`GetSystemMetrics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the standard size of a small icon, scaled for the current system DPI. This will be good enough, if your application is only **system-DPI-aware**. If your application is **per-Monitor-DPI-aware**, you may be interested in [`GetSystemMetricsForDpi()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748625(v=vs.85).aspx), which has been added by a recent Windows 10 update.

Comment: Thanks for this - I did not know LoadIconWithScaleDown but that was not exactly my question.  A large portion of my code reads pngs as a HICON (I did not write this) and I want to be able to resize the HICON I receive into a new HICON.

Comment: @BadJerry You should edit your question to add that important information. It should have been there from the beginning so we wouldn't had to waste our time giving inadequate answers.

Comment: Sincere apologies @zett42 - I truly appreciate your help though (and I have learned something). Will do that now.

Answer (score 3):

Get DPI scale using `GetDeviceCaps` and divide by `96` to obtain DPI factor.

Multiply the icon size by this DPI factor. Example,

```
int default_size = 16;
CClientDC dc(GetDesktopWindow());
int logpixy = dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY);
size = MulDiv(default_size, logpixy, 96);

hicon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
            MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, size, size, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
button.SetIcon(hicon);
```

You will need to store different icon sizes. For example 16x16, 20x20, 24x24, 32x32.

If the exact size is not available then `LoadImage` will pick the closest match.

Comment: I suggest to replace `LoadImage` with [`LoadIconWithScaleDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703(v=vs.85).aspx) which is available since Windows Vista. This will greatly improve image quality in cases where an exact match of the desired image size is not available in the icon resource. In this case, `LoadImage` would load the image with the next *lower* size and scale that up, whereas `LoadIconWithScaleDown` loads the next *bigger* image and scale that down, which makes the scaled image appear more detailed and sharper.

Comment: @zett42 That makes things a lot easier. You should change the comment to a separate answer.

Comment: I was a bit lazy. Thanks for encouraging me to overcome that. :)

Comment: Thanks for this - I am repeating what I have written above: that was not exactly my question. A large portion of my code reads pngs as a HICON (I did not write this) and I want to be able to resize the HICON I receive into a new HICON

Comment: You can use `USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI` instead of `96` value.